# SQL Server 2016 Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportbuilder3.0

We need to Export rdls, that were created by report builder, in C#.
We have used the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll Version 12.0.0.0 and have called the Render function for this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms252752(v=vs.100)

Since we now also support SQL Server 2016, we have to upgrade the dll to support the new report builder version.
But I can't find a newer version of the dll.

[image]

So how do I export reports for SQL Server 2016 in C#?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution on my own. I didn't find a source where I can download the new dll.
But if I download this package it contains the new dll with the Version number 14.0 instead of 12.0.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/140.1000.523

So I took the dlls I needed, added them to the Solution and referenced them in the project. Now I can render rdls generated with report builder 2016.

[image]